# Another unterminated 's' command

Tags: shell-script, sed, scripting

I am trying to make a simple replacement for an IPv4 address script.

```
sed "s/[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}/192.100.100.100/g"
```

This is what I have. As stated in the title I am receiving an unterminated 's' command.

Edit: I am running on Windows,connecting to a Unix machine through ssh.

I originally had:

```
 sed 's/[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}/192.100.100.100/g'
```

But I changed it from single quotes to double quotes because something may have not being read as intended and that may have been causing my error. I tested it and still the results remained the same "unterminated 's' command".

Any ideas or advice would be great!

**Entire Script**

```
#!/bin/sed -f

#sed 's/[^@ ]*@[^@]*\.[^@ ]*\.[^@]*/account@example.com/g'

#sed 's/[^@]*\.[^@]*\.[^@]*/example.com/g'

sed "s/[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}/192.100.100.100/g"
```

Example File Input:

```
From: Mail System Internal Data <example@a.b.c>
Subject: DON'T DELETE THIS MESSAGE -- FOLDER INTERNAL DATA
X-IMAP: 1322061792 0000000000
Status: RO

Email message goes here.

From example@a.b.c Tue Nov 22 15:24:01 2011 -0500
Status: R
X-Status:
X-Keywords:
Return-Path: <spam.spam.a@b.c>
X-Original-To: example@a.b.c
Delivered-To: example@a.b.c
```

Comment: The only difference between single and double quotes is whether variable and command substitution is done. Since there are no variables, backticks or `$()`, you shouldn't need to use double quotes.

Comment: @terdon I see your case and point. I fixed it and will be better about adding all of the details in the future. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your script is a `sed` script, not a shell script. So you don't need to put `sed` at the beginning of the line, or put quotes around the commands. Change it to:

```
#!/bin/sed -f

s/[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}/192.100.100.100/g
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. That makes a lot of sense now. I will not be making that mistake again, hopefully.